# SQLite, selecting values having same criteria (throughout all table)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, conditional-statements

I have an sqlite database table similar to the one given below

```
Name   | Surname | AddrType | Age | Phone
John   | Kruger  | Home     | 23  | 12345
Sarah  | Kats    | Home     | 33  | 12345
Bill   | Kruger  | Work     | 15  | 12345
Lars   | Kats    | Home     | 54  | 12345
Javier | Roux    | Work     | 45  | 12345
Ryne   | Hutt    | Home     | 36  | 12345
```

I would like to select Name values matching same "Surname" value for each of the rows in the table.

For example, for the first line the query would be "select Name from myTable where Surname='Kruger'" whereas for the second line the query would be "select Name from myTable where Surname='Kats' and so an....

Is it possible to traverse through the whole table and select all values like that?

PS : I will use these method in a C++ application, the alternative method is to use sqlite3_exec() and process each row one by one. I just want to know if there is any other possible way for the same approach.

Comment: How should the result of the query look? Please show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do:

```
sqlite> SELECT group_concat(Name, '|') Names FROM People GROUP BY Surname;
Names
----------
Ryne
Sarah|Lars
John|Bill
Javier
```

Then split each value of "Names" in C++ using the "|" separator (or any other you choose in group_concat function.

Comment: Thanks.... What if I want to insert these values to a new column? For example, if I have one extra column (say JoinNames) and I would like to insert "John,Bill" into this column where Surname = Kruger?

Comment: New column of a **new** table or the **same** table? In case of the same table do you want each row where Surname = 'Kruger' to have the **same** JoinNames value of 'John,Bill'?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just want to exclude any records that don't have a buddy.

Something simple like joining the table against itself should work:

```
SELECT a.Name 
FROM tab AS a
JOIN tab AS b 
    ON a.Surname = b.Surname;
```

Just returning the full sorted table and doing the duplicate check yourself may be faster if incidence is high (and will always be high for all sets of data).  That would be a pretty strong assumption though.

```
SELECT Name
FROM tab
SORT BY Surname;
```